# Manipulating 80 bits datatype in C

Tags: c, cryptography, rotation, fpga, bit-shift

I'm implementing some cryptographic algorithm in C which involves an 80 bits key.
A particular operation involves a rotate shifting the key x number of bits.

I've tried the long double type which if I'm not wrong is 80bits, but that doesn't work with the bitshift operator.

The only alternative I can come up with is to use a 10 element char array with some complicated looping and if-else.

My question is whether there's some simple and efficient way of carrying this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the PC1 algorithm? My understanding is that the 80bit version is used on other (not x86) architectures such as the Motorola 6809? Can you give a platform?

Comment: Just use an array of char and implement your own shift/rotate - see here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918229/how-to-circular-shift-an-array-of-4-chars

Comment: Hi,nope it's the PRESENT block cipher algorithm.

http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~abogdano/papers/present_ches07.pdf

I'm trying to implement it in C on a xilinx microblaze fpga board.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I will study that thread.

Comment: If you are on 64bit platforms with gcc or cousins you have _uint128_t that implements all arithmetic on 128 types. These are usually synthesized operations, so you could look up the source on how this is done.

Comment: `long double` is 80 bits in GNU GCC for x86, because of native support by the FPU.  Not all compilers do that for x86 FPU; in MSVC++ for example it is a synonym for `double`. But as you say it is academic since shifts and other bit-wise operators are integer operations.  I suggest that you implement the necessary 80-bit operations in your FPGA.

Comment: There's no point in using chars - you're wasting cycles. Use the largest integral datatype your architecture has to offer, probably at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly you need a bignum library. While C native data types have support for 80 bit floats it doesn't actually do what you want.

It is possible to link something like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) or even use a less desirable approaches like 10 character array or two numbers a long and short (64bit and 16bit integers).

Neither is particularly pretty but they do work and if you're planning on using this for anything but a class, [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) is the way to go. Otherwise you could end up with a whole mess of timing attacks which you could code around but it could get really nasty, real quick.

Comment: It's the PRESENT block cipher algorithm. 
homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~abogdano/papers/present_ches07.pdf 

I'm trying to implement it in C on a xilinx microblaze fpga board.

Comment: Are you aiming for ultra efficient or just fairly?

Comment: Fair efficiency will do as well I suppose.

Comment: Why would you be implementing this in C when you have an FPGA?

Comment: I'm trying to compare and assess the speedup of the FPGA implementation against a fairly efficient C implementation.

Comment: [this](www.lightweightcrypto.org/downloads/implementations/present.h) is a nice implementation fo this in C, with sbox's processed out.  It's faster than what you'll most likely implement since they actually did the math to expand the polynomials.

Comment: This makes little sense. The C implementation is guaranteed to be slower then the FPGA if the C code runs on the FPGA. This is guaranteed because the soft processor performs extra tasks (such as reading code). The alternative is to compare x86 to FPGA which makes slightly more sense.

Comment: @user1289618: A rotate operation on an 80-bit register on an FPGA could be implemented in a single cycle.  A software implementation in C using an array of 5 16bit integers, will take several 10's of machine cycles depending on many factors including compiler optimisation, and target instruction set.  For the same clock rate, the C implementation will be much slower. What more do you need to know?  Further, the ability to pipe-line and parallel operations in an FPGA implementation can mean that an algorithm will scale better on an FPGA than on a sequential processor.

Comment: Thanks for the replies people. 
I do know that the fpga implementation will be a lot faster. However, this is a school project and I am required to come up with both implementations for comparison.

Answer (score 4):

There is something a bit messed up here. If I understand you correctly, you are using a "soft" cpu on the FPGA.

1. Traditionally, people use the FPGA to make their own shift registers through VHDL/Verilog. These kind of algorithms are fairly painless to implement and very fast. Back at the university I did this is for a cryptography project.
2. Moreover, the paper you mentioned talks about a 128 bit key. This would be significantly easier to implement?

Comment: The paper also mentioned that the algorithm works for both 80 bits and 128 bits key. The former is the lightweight version which I'm attempting to implement here.

Comment: That's a good point: if you're using an FPGA, you can build the algorithm right in, rather than running it on a soft CPU.