# How to define 80-bit long variable in Python to generate random .onion addresses?

Tags: python, tor, custom-data-type

I'm trying to implement some random generator of [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)) [.onion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion) addresses which involves generation of 80-bit numbers to create 16-character hashes.

How do I define such variable in Python?

[.onion format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion#Format):

> "16-character hashes can be made up of any letter of the alphabet, and
>   decimal digits beginning with 2 and ending with 7, thus representing
>   an 80-bit number in base32."

Links:

- [Manipulating 80 bits datatype in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849764/manipulating-80-bits-datatype-in-c)

Comment: Shouldn't a long (python 2) or an int (python 3) just work straight out?

Comment: How do I know they're 80-bit long and they won't overflow?

Comment: `random.getrandbits(80)`

Comment: @kenorb - Because they're defined that way in python.

Answer (score 4):

You want this one-liner if you are on Python3

```
import base64
import codecs
import random

data = base64.b32encode(
    codecs.decode(codecs.encode(
        '{0:020x}'.format(random.getrandbits(80))
    ), 'hex_codec')
)
```

Explanation: You grab your 80 random bits using [`random.getrandbits`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.getrandbits), encode it into binary form (which you kind of have to go through the process by going through the hex encoding, then use the [`base64.b32encode`](https://docs.python.org/library/base64.html#base64.b32encode) function, which provides the [RFC 3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html) compliant method of encoding this into your target encoding of base32.

Works for Python 2 also.

Comment: Python 3.3: `LookupError: unknown encoding: hex`. It should be [`hex_codec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms).

Comment: Oh, I tested this in python3.4 which was installed on my system.  Confirmed not to work on python3.2 either. Thanks for that @Matthias.

Comment: Works for me on Python 2.7.5 & 3.4.1 (OSX). Code: `import random,base64,codecs; base64.b32encode(codecs.decode(codecs.encode('{0:020x}'.format(random.getrandbits(80))),'hex_codec')).lower();`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a sequence of 10 bytes encoding an 80 bit random  number like this:

```
import struct
import random

number = random.randint(0, 2**80)
data = struct.pack("qH", number >> 16, number & 16)
```

**update**

Sorry, teh above part does not take care about the encoding of the key in Base32 - 
without resorting to Python's string codecs (see metatoaster's answer for that) a compact and readable form is:

```
import string
import random

digits = string.lowercase + "234567"

res = ""
n = random.randrange(2**80)
for _ in range(16):
    res += digits[n & 0b11111]
    n >>= 5
```

Comment: Or just use `struct.pack("10B", number)`. This avoids worrying about what endianess is used for the multi-byte values.

Comment: This raises `struct.error: argument out of range` if the number is "not clean", such as `658690783642833129621763`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you actually need the alphanumeric representation of the 80-bit hash, just select the base-32 digits directly.

```
digits = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567"
address = "".join(random.choice(digits) for _ in range(16))
```

I found a 15% speed-up by avoiding repeated name lookups for `random.choice` and by using a list comprehension rather than passing a generator to `"".join`.

```
from random import choice
digits = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz234567"
address = "".join([choice(digits) for _ in range(16)])
```

Comment: This looks clean but takes about 110% the time of my solution according to `timeit`, but I don't think it matters in a one-off call.

Comment: How much of the 10% can we shave off if you save a reference to `random.choice` first? :)  ( `rc=random.choice; "".join(rc(digits) for _ in range(16)`)

Comment: There is also a little bit of speed up if you use a list comprehension rather than a generator as the argument to `"".join`. (Paradoxical, but it's because `"".join` has to build a list anyway in order to compute how much space to allocate for the result.)